# Recursively compute the value of base to the n power

Tags: java, recursion

Here is what I have for my solution:

```
 public int powerN(int base, int n) {

    if(n == 0)
       return 1;

    else if(n % 2 == 0)
       return base * base;

    else
       return base * powerN(base, n-1); 

 }
```

However, if n > 3 then this function doesn't work.
For instance, powerN(2, 4) yields 4 and powerN(2, 5) yields 8.
I know that a much simpler solution exists, but it just bothers me that I can't figure out why this is not working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Into pseudocode

Let me translate your code into pseudocode:

```
public int powerN(int base, int exponent)  {
    if the exponent is 0
        then return 1
    otherwise, if the exponent is even
        then return base * base
    otherwise
        base * powerN(base, exponent - 1)
}
```

The second branch has a logic error. What your code is saying is this: "As long as the exponent is even, the result should be `base * base` (that is, `base` squared)". You've already mentioned that this is the result you get when you run your code.

### How to solve it

What you probably want to do is to raise `base` to half the `exponent` (`base * base * base * ...` for `exponent / 2` times), and then multiply that number by itself. That way, you get `base` multiplied by itself `exponent` times.

In pseudocode:

```
otherwise, if the exponent is even
    then return powerN(base, exponent / 2) * powerN(base, exponent / 2)
```

Realistically, this would actually be the following:

```
otherwise, if the exponent is even
    then {
        let x = powerN(base, exponent / 2)
        return x * x
    }
```

### Done. Mostly.

Translate that back to Java and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. After tracing through the code, it makes sense as to why that statement is needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
else if(n % 2 == 0)
   return base * base;
```

This bit is incorrect — it returns the square for any even power, not just 2. It looks like you’re trying to implement the [square and multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) optimization. So if you want to compute `powerN(base, n)`, what recursive call can you make that takes advantage of the fact that `n` is even? What new values will you pass in for `base` and `n`? Use the identity that *b*<sup>2‌*n*</sup> = (*b*<sup>2</sup>)<sup>*n*</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Buggy code is:

```
else if(n % 2 == 0)
   return base * base;
```

this if will catch every power of 2. So `0,2,4,8` causes wrong calculation.

The only **corner case** you should worry about is **when `n <= 0`**.

Here is corrected code:

```
public static int powerN(int base, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Power Argument");
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return base * powerN(base, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NullPointerException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(powerN(2, i));
    }
}
```

and output:

```
run:
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Not really. The case where n ==2 is an important optimization that saves a recursion.

Answer (score 1):

In the even case you need `base = powerN(base, n/2);`before returning.

Comment: Because the way it was it did not depend on `n`. Now you're computing `b^(2k)` as `(b^k)^2`, when `n=2k`.

Answer (score 0):

For computing the power you only need to consider the special case of x^0, for all others (n>0) you can use the recursion of x*powerN(x, n-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square{
    int r=1;
     int power(int n, int p) throws Exception
    {
         int s=n;
        if(n<0||p<0)
        {
        throw new Exception("n and p must be positive");
        }

    if(p==2)
    {
        return n*n*r;
    }
    else
    {
        r=r*n;
        return power(n,p-1);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer in C++, this is a series of a^b =

```
int power(int a, int b)
{
   int k = a;
   int c = b;
   if (c == 1)
    {
        return a;
    }
   else if (c == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
   else if (c >= 1)
   {
        c--;
        k = k*power(k,c);
   }
   cout << k << endl;
   return k;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number " << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter power " << endl;
    int c1 = 0;
    cin >> c1;
    cout << endl ;
    cout << "These are all the powers up to " << n << " to the power " << c1 << endl;
    power(n,c1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int powerN(int base, int n ){
    if (n==0){
        return 1;
    }else
        return base*powerN(base,n-1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the code

if (n % 2 == 0)
     return base * base;

This makes your function return square of the base whenevr the power (n) is even and cube  whenever it is odd.
The only terminating condition u need is n==0 return 1 and it should work to your specification of base to the power n recursively

Answer (score -1):

```
public int powerN(int base, int power) {
    if (power == 1)
        return base;
    else if (power % 2 == 0) {
        int x = powerN(base, power / 2);
        return x * x;
    } else {
        int x = powerN(base, (power - 1) / 2);
        return x * x * base;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide explanation how this code solves the OP's problem. What is the difference of your code to the OP's code? How does your code solve the problem?